# Cut 1 big image into small images with the same size

Tags: php, image, gd

Given a JPG image, cut off it in horizontal direction so that the size of spic is around 100K

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you find any problems?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be possible to cut them *by size*, as compression ratio depends on type of data. In other words, one 100KB image will be with larger dimensions (width, height) than another 100KB image. You might use some uncompressed format (e.g., bmp) to avoid this, but that's usually not a good idea.

Comment: By 'cut' you mean, by chance, resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have used this function in the past works well for me...

This will take an input file and create tiles of the specified size...

```
function makeTiles($name, $imageFileName, $crop_width, $crop_height)
{
    $dir = "source dir";
    $slicesDir = "target dir";

    // might be good to check if $slicesDir exists etc if not create it.

    $inputFile = $dir . $imageFileName;

    $img = new Imagick($inputFile);
    $imgHeight = $img->getImageHeight();
    $imgWidth = $img->getImageWidth();

        $cropWidthTimes = ceil($imgWidth/$crop_width);
    $cropHeightTimes = ceil($imgHeight/$crop_height);
    for($i = 0; $i < $cropWidthTimes; $i++)
    {
        for($j = 0; $j < $cropHeightTimes; $j++)
        {
            $img = new Imagick($inputFile);
            $x = ($i * $crop_width);
            $y = ($j * $crop_height);
            $img->cropImage($crop_width, $crop_height, $x, $y);
            $data = $img->getImageBlob();
            $newFileName = $slicesDir . $name . "_" . $x . "_" . $y . ".jpg";
            $result = file_put_contents ($newFileName, $data);
        }
    }
}
```